# trying to get the inner text content of a span element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a search bar that will allow the user to search an array of items. I'm using a `span` element as my filter, but for some reason, I can't get the contents of the element to assign to a variable.

It's a pretty straight forward setup.

I grab the contents of the class wrapping the list, then grab each span element. For sanity reasons I `console.log` the span elements to ensure they are captured (which, they are).

I then attempt to grab the text contents within and assign it to a `txtValue` variable which I would then proceed to do a comparison check with the filter.

The part where I assign it to a text value is where the bug occurs, it doesn't seem to grab the inner text. Perhaps I'm going about this wrong?

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, e, content, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  e = document.getElementById("search-list");
  content = e.getElementsByTagName("span");
  console.log(content);
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content) {
      txtValue = content.innerHTML;
      console.log(textValue);
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        content[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        content[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="search()"placeholder="Search for numbers">
</div>

<div id="search-list">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>  
  <span>3</span>  
  <span>4</span>  
  <span>5</span>  
</div>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array like element.  Not a single element (notice the Element**s**).  So you have to loop over them before you can do `.innerHTML`

Comment: I overlooked that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- content is an nodelist and you need to access index to access node
- you defined variable as `txtValue` in console you're using `textValue`

```js
function search() {
  var input, filter, e, content, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("search");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  e = document.getElementById("search-list");
  content = e.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content) {
      txtValue = content[i].innerHTML;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        content[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        content[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search-bar">
  <input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="search()"placeholder="Search for numbers">
</div>

<div id="search-list">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>  
  <span>3</span>  
  <span>4</span>  
  <span>5</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use:

txtValue = content[i].innerHTML;